# Devices not able to connect to PC local proxy server on home network

Tags: networking, proxy, http-proxy, proxy-server

So my PC wasn't wanting to connect to my WiFi for some days now, and I was getting kinda tired of having to share my phone's connection and not being able to be directly connected to my home's network to go on my personal server (had to remove the disk to change the files). So I got tired and Googled how I could fix it. The first page (Quora) is the following: https://www.quora.com/What-causes-limited-connectivity-from-a-laptop-to-wifi. The answer I followed was Rajiv's and I did the 1st and 3rd steps. After the first one, I rebooted as he says. Didn't work. So I tried the second (didn't reboot). Didn't work either. So I thought in disabling some items on the WiFi properties. Didn't work either. Then I had the idea to put original DNS (and then back to Google's, after...) --> worked finally. Now I just have a small problem... I have a local proxy for testing purposes, but now no device can connect to it! Nor another proxy program I had here by chance. I also tried System Restore to some days earlier (was the only one available). Broke some programs, and didn't fix it (cool).

Please, does anyone know how to fix this damn thing? I've tried to think what to ask Google but I had no success finding anything useful.

Thanks in advance for any help!

PS: I hope this is the right StackExchange website to ask this :). If it's not, I'm sorry. I get confused with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was my Firewall blocking the proxy. I remember having gone on it and deleted some rules I didn't know what they were. I had no idea I was deleting a rule that allowed the proxy to run... The other one started working some hours ago for some reason. The one I wanted I had to put a rule to allow any local addresses with any port to communicate with any other addresses and ports. This is weird. I'd love to know what I did before not to have to do this...